# Troubleshooting with PHP Syntax

Tags: php, magento, syntax

I need help with php syntax below. Because I have several storeviews with magento, the Bold word **Warenkorb** should be replaced by something like the following:

```
<?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?>
```

so that with other storeviews the word Warenkorb will be translated.

Does anybody know how to do this?

```
<?php

  //get total items in cart
  $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();

  //get total price
  $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

  if( $count == 0 ) {
    echo $this->__(' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.cococana.de/index.php/checkout/cart/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Warenkorb: <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp %s',$count);
  }

  if( $count == 1 ) {
    echo $this->__(' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.cococana.de/index.php/checkout/cart/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Warenkorb <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp',$count);
  }

  if( $count > 1 ) {
    echo $this->__(' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.cococana.de/index.php/checkout/cart/">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Warenkorb: <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp %s',$count);
  }

  echo $this->__(' Artikel: %s', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));

?>
```

Comment: Use css to get your spacing...

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here.

Comment: @Alan: I think hes asking how to make a translation file for Magento, but i cant be sure...

Comment: @rekire: In `&nbsp;` no one can hear you scream?

Comment: I think @prodigitalson is correct. This appears to be a request for translating labels in Magento. Relevant, maybe: [How to install Magento Frontend Localization](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-install-magento-frontend-localization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Translation in magento is done via the block and helper methods `__()` which you are already using.

They accept any number of arguments. The first argument is the string with optional placeholders (%s), the following arguments act as the replacements of the placeholders.

You´re already using this, too.

The strings are to be translated according to related translation files, which you have to supply. 
Read [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/BLOG-Localization_in_Magento_%282%29.pdf) for more information.

And yes.. use css for spacing. Not only because you have to use the string in your translation files too (which would be a huge PITA with all that `&nbsp;`), but separation of layout and content is considered a best practice since decades i guess.